# UIView w. Dynamic Height Above TableView Overlapping TableCells When Resized Programatically

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

I have added a "header" `UIView` of sorts above my tableview. The header `UIView` is being used to display a status update posted by a user.Statuses in my app range from a single line to several lines worth of text so what ive done is added code in my VC to programatically resize the "Header" UIView so that all the text will fit. Resizing the header `UIView` has worked perfectly as planned. The only side effect is that when the UIView's frame is made larger it starts to overlap the first cell in my table which is undesired.

Any clue why this is happening and/or how to solve it? If I make the `UIView` bigger or smaller from my storyboard this side effect doesnt occur so I dint expect it to come up when making the `UIView` bigger programatically. I figured the Table would just know to push the table cell down.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the way table header views behave. If you drag a view into a UITableView, it becomes a tableHeaderView. To get rid of the undesired overlap, you have to re-declare that view as the tableHeaderView after you make the size change. So, if you had a property pointing to this view called header, do this:

```
// do your resizing here
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
```

Comment: This works for me, but should be `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header`

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to make the view as the section header of the table view and implement the `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method, or just tweak the table view's frame after the "header" view resized.